# Why is no one using Deep Quantile Regression as alternative to MDNs?

Tags: regression, neural-networks, multiple-regression, quantile-regression

There are numerous articles and implementations of Mixture Density Networks, however I have seen almost no literature in regards to using Quantile Regression with Deep Learning.

Why is this the case? Is there some disadvantage to "Deep Quantile Regression" compared to MDNs that I am missing?

To those unfamiliar with the term, [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-quantile-regression-c85481548b5a) and [here](https://ig248.gitlab.io/post/2019-05-18-deepquantiles-p3/) are examples of such approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The post uses toy examples only, but in reality quantiles are not that easy.
When talking about uncertainty estimation (a possible use-case of mixture densities), quantile regression display the worst result in the small data regime (see Fig 11 [here](https://www.inovex.de/blog/uncertainty-quantification-deep-learning/)). Eventually they converge with other methods asymptotically to GP level performance in the big data regime.

Asking about reasons, though, is harder.
Usage varies due to several, non-scientific, factors, including the availability of code, 'hype' and prominent publications.
And I suspect the reasons why are much more random and less pragmatic than one would like.